Check resource reference dependency in ARM template
I have the template below where I am checking whether database exist before assignment the principals, but I am still having problems with ADF doesn't exist, I assume this is happening in the properties, but I wasn't able to find the solution.
I have added an if statement in that reference, but I still having the same problem. How can bypass this?
My ARM template:
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "0.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "clusterName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "databaseIDPrincipals": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "databaseADFPrincipals": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "databaseSYNPrincipals": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": ""
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[empty(resourceId('Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases', parameters('clusterName'), parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].databaseName))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/principalAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-11-09",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '/', parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].databaseName, '/', concat(parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalId, parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].role))]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "databaseIDPrincipalsCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('databaseIDPrincipals'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "principalId": "[parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalId]",
        "role": "[parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].role]",
        "tenantId": "[parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].tenantId]",
        "principalType": "[parameters('databaseIDPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalType]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[empty(resourceId('Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases', parameters('clusterName'), parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].databaseName))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/principalAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-11-09",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '/', parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].databaseName, '/', concat(parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalId, parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].role))]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "databaseADFPrincipalsCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('databaseADFPrincipals'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].subscriptionId, parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalId), '2018-06-01','Full').identity.principalId]",
        "role": "[parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].role]",
        "tenantId": "[parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].tenantId]",
        "principalType": "[parameters('databaseADFPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalType]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[empty(resourceId('Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases', parameters('clusterName'), parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].databaseName))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/principalAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-11-09",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '/', parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].databaseName, '/', concat(parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalId, parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].role))]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "databaseSYNPrincipalsCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals'))]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].subscriptionId, parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].resourceGroup, 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces', parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalId), '2021-06-01','Full').identity.principalId]",
        "role": "[parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].role]",
        "tenantId": "[parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].tenantId]",
        "principalType": "[parameters('databaseSYNPrincipals')[copyIndex()].principalType]"
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}

My error:



Reference dependency in ARM template

In general, the issue you mentioned occurs when the format for referencing the Data factory resource (Microsoft.DataFactory/factories) is not found during the deployment.
Make sure this resource is readily available while running the arm template. You can also use if function or add validation logic to check the existence of resources.
I tried to sample arm template where you will be able to fetch the resource existence as per the requirement.
ARM template:
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "0.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "clusterName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "testvvvk"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ADF and Synapse Principal Assignment"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/principalAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-11-09",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '/testdbvkks/0d8bdfe2-c6ac-4a0a-af35-f9600bccf6a6')]",
      "properties": {
        "principalId": "",
        "role": "Admin",  // Use a valid Kusto database role
        "tenantId": "",
        "principalType": "App"  // Changed to valid value
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/principalAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-11-09",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '/testdbvkks/sampleadfvkks')]",
      "properties": {
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('', 'vinay-rg', 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', 'sampleadfvkks'), '2018-06-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
        "role": "Viewer",  // Use a valid Kusto database role
        "tenantId": "",
        "principalType": "App"  // Changed to valid value
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Kusto/clusters/databases/principalAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-11-09",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('clusterName'), '/testdbvkks/samplesyvkksb')]",
      "properties": {
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('', 'vinay-rg', 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces', 'samplesyvkksb'), '2021-06-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
        "role": "User",  // Use a valid Kusto database role
        "tenantId": "",
        "principalType": "App"  // Changed to valid value
      },
      "tags": {
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Description": "[parameters('description')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Deployment:
az deployment group create --resource-group vinay-rg --template-file armtemplate.json --parameters clusterName=testvvvk description="ADF and Synapse Principal Assignment"



Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/add-database-principal?tabs=csharp
https://shisho.dev/dojo/providers/azurerm/Data_Explorer/azurerm-kusto-database-principal-assignment/
